# Typescript - clone the backend model in the frontend

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am facing a decision problem where in the backend, there is a data model (e.g. Document), whose data structure is like:
{
   "file_name": string,
   "uploaded_time": date,
}

Then, my question is for the react frontend with typescript, do I need to add a type/interface/class to specify the same data structure again in the frontend for some form of validation.

Not sure how it is generally handled. what is the benefit to add the same data structure again in the frontend? and what is the drawback (one could be the synchronisation later whenever the backend model changes)?

Comment: So the short answer is: yes, you'll have to clone the backend model in TypeScript if you want type safety on the frontend. That being said, there are tools that will do this for you, although they're not really applicable in all circumstances. Or, if you are also using TypeScript in your backend, you can just share the interface from the same `.ts` file. If all of this is too much work, you can write `type MyType = any` and call it a day, but that is generally a last-ditch resort.

Comment: Hey Matt thanks. but what is the benefits of cloning the same data structure in the frontend again? any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, duplicate it.

Another solution is to use code generation; grpc, swagger, graphql all follow this approach.

Another solution is to use typescript in the backend also.